# How do I bind to an object in my model to a user control in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to populate labels in a user control. The code-behind my user control creates an object, and I'm trying to bind the label contents to properties in that object. The class creating the object implements `INotifyPropertyChanges`, and has several public properties. I created binding within the XAML, and Visual Studio has picked this up, with intellisense offering me the properties to bind to.  However, when I run, the labels are all blank.
If I create a property directly in my code behind which just calls from the object (and appropriately change my datacontext), it works.

I'm not too experienced with WPF - I must have missed something but I just don't know what?!

When my XAML looks like this, neither label is populated.  If I adjust the data context to the control rather than the `instrument` object, The `ConStatus` label appropriately populates (but does not update as the user control doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChange`:

```
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding instrument}">
            <Label Name="PortName" Width="100" Content="{Binding ConnectionString}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Label  Name="ConStatus" Width="200" Content="{Binding UniName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </WrapPanel>
```

My code-behind looks like this:

```
Public Class UnifaceControl
    Inherits UserControl

    Public instrument As UnifaceModel

    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        FindUniface("uniface")
    End Sub

    Public Sub FindUniface(Portname As String)
        instrument = New UnifaceModel(Portname)
        instrument.Connect()
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property UniName
        Get
            Return instrument.Connected
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

And here's a sample of the UnifaceModel object:

```
Public Class UnifaceModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Shared Log As NLog.Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()

    Dim _ConnectionString As String
    Public Property ConnectionString As String
        Get
            Return _ConnectionString
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ConnectionString = value
            OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instrument` must be a *property*  for you to be able to bind to it:

```
Public Property instrument As UnifaceModel
```

But you also need to set the `DataContext` of the control or its parent window somewhere:

```
Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Set the DataContext to itself
    DataContext = Me

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    FindUniface("uniface")
End Sub
```

Since you currently bind to properties of both `UserControl` itself and `instrument`, you should not bind the `DataContext` to `instrument`:

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Label Name="PortName" Width="100" Content="{Binding instrument.ConnectionString}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Label  Name="ConStatus" Width="200" Content="{Binding UniName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: This is so obvious now you've said it, and I'm kicking myself.  Thank you!